# React - Bootstrap: Offcanvas with embedded mapped tabs content disappearing on Re-Render

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a React application that includes a Bootstrap Offcanvas component with embedded Tabs. For the Tabs and Content, they are created from an array of Table components which is mapped to create them dynamically. These Table components take a container as input, which I used a Ref to bind them to the dynamically generated Tabs. The first render works perfectly, however; when I close the Offcanvas and open it again, the Tab content is now empty. I'm assuming this is an issue with the Ref.

Here is the code for the Tab component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import Tabs from "react-bootstrap/Tabs";
import Tab from "react-bootstrap/Tab";

function LayerResults({featureTables, mapView, placeFeatureTables}) {
    const resultRef = useRef(featureTables.map(() => React.createRef()));

useEffect(()=> {
    if (featureTables.length) {
        placeFeatureTables(resultRef);
    } 
}, [mapView])

return (
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey={featureTables[0].layer.title} className="tableResults">
        {featureTables && featureTables.map((table, i) => {
            return (
                <Tab
                    className="TableTab"
                    title={`${table.layer.title.slice(0,10)}...`}
                    eventKey={table.layer.title}
                    key={`${i}`}
                >
                    <div ref={resultRef.current[i]}></div>
                </Tab>
            )
        })}
    </Tabs>
)
};
```

And here's the code for the *placeFeatureTables()* function from an even higher component that the useEffect uses which updates the *featureTables* state with the container / Ref.

```
  const placeFeatureTables = (containerRefs) => {
    setFeatureTables(prev => {
      const placedTables = prev.map((table, i) => {
        table.container = containerRefs.current[i].current;
        return table;
      })
      return placedTables;
    })
  }
```

I feel like this is most likely the issue area and the Containers / Refs are not being updated properly on re-render and I should be using something other than useRef. The thing that's really bugging me though, is that I swear this was working earlier.

Note1: The FeatureTables come from ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API. Although, it's just the Ref being passed, so I don't think it's necessary to know about them. [FeatureTable Documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-FeatureTable.html)

Note2: If I console.log the featureTables. The first time, the container highlights the area where it's at. Once I close and re-open and then click on the new featureTables container, it says the node does not exist.